# Promise in the if statement (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I want to use promise results in the if statements, however when I try to, I get something like this:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
setTimeout(() => {
  resolve(5 * 2)
}, 1000)
})

console.log(promise.then(i => i) === 10) //false
```

Is it possible to somehow wait for the extraction of the promise result in this case?

Comment: Put the `console.log` inside the `then` callback: `promise.then(i => { console.log(i == 10); })`. And no, you can't get the boolean result immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to use it in a more synchronous fashion.

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(5 * 2)
  }, 1000)
});

(async () => {
  console.log(await promise === 10);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the result of the `Promise` within `then`.

```
console.log(promise.then(i => i === 10))
```

This will log the promise object anyway. If you want to log the result:

```
promise.then(i => console.log(i === 10))
```

To make it clearer, see the lambda written with more syntax hints:

```
promise.then(    (i) => { console.log(i === 10); }    );
```

Or even as an anonymous function:

```
promise.then(   function(i){ console.log(i === 10); }  );
```

Here you prepare the behavior beforehand and then pass it:

```
var myTimeoutHandler = function(i){
    console.log(i === 10); 
};
promise.then(myTimeoutHandler);
```

The `i => ...` syntax is a shorthand for this.

In general, with `Promise` (and ReactiveX's [`Observable`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) alike), you are reacting to something, so you are providing the behavior by passing a callback (here in a form of a lambda). So every action that needs to work with whatever comes processed needs to be within the callback.

Read more about [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Answer (score 0):

You can only work with the value of a Promise inside of a function passed to `then` –

```js
const delay = x =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 1000, x))
 
delay (5*2) .then (console.log)
// 10

delay (5*2) .then (x => x === 10) .then (console.log)
// true
```

Or inside of an `async` function using the `await` keyword –

```js
const delay = x =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 1000, x))
 
const main = async () =>
{ const x = await delay (5*2)
  console.log (x) 
  console.log (x === 10)
  return 'done'
}

main () .then (console.log)
// 10
// true
// done
```

Comment: You can work with the value of the Promise outside of a function passed to `then` when using async/await. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825490/1911755)

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah thanks for mentioning `await`